# Fill an array in matrix form (2D ARRAY)

Tags: java

I need to make an array which has 4 rows and 4 columns, and the user enter numbers and fills the array in matrix form (2D-ARRAY).

```
package javaapplication6;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaApplication6 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] arr=new int[4][4];
        System.out.println("Enter numbers");
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
                arr[i][j]=obj.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
                System.out.println("\t"+arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a *matrix form*? In addition are you aware you use a 6x6 array in your code?

Comment: If i use for(int i=0;i<4;i++){ for(int j=0;j<4;j++){ arr[i][j]=obj.nextInt(); } i DO THIS BUT ITS NOT WORKING JAVA EXCEPTION ERROR COME

Comment: Please complete your question with the full description of the problem (including the exception content). See [ask]. *It's not working* doesn't help.

Comment: Btw. your array is 5 x 5; if you want a 4 x 4 array, it should be int[3][3].

Answer (score 0):

your array is of size 4X4 and your for loop is iterating 6X6 times.

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
       arr[i][j]=obj.nextInt();
   }
```

rectify the problem in the the next for loop too.

Comment: If i use for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
       arr[i][j]=obj.nextInt();
   } i DO THIS BUT ITS NOT WORKING JAVA EXCEPTION ERROR COME

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at javaapplication6.JavaApplication6.main(JavaApplication6.java:23)
Java Result: 1   THIS ERROR WILL COME

Comment: @Hameed_Khan: This detail about the exception should be included in your post, because it describes the problem and help answering. You can edit your post using the `Edit` button below it.